# BlueZ 5.58 Connection Fail

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, bluetooth, bluez

I am working on the BlueZ 5.58 library using the Raspberry Pi 4. So far, I am able to install an updated version of the BlueZ 5.58 & making sample test cases. (refrance [BLE GATT Server](https://scribles.net/creating-ble-gatt-server-uart-service-on-raspberry-pi/))

While reconnecting the GATT Server(Raspberry Pi) using the GATT Client(android application) many times the connection failed status shown on the app.
I have enabled the debug logs to trace the code. But in that case, no log statements are printed.

Will you please help me to know, why this is happening? How can I solve this?

Comment: are the debug logs you mention on the phone or the pi?

Comment: @JaromandaX: I have enabled the debug logs on Raspberry Pi where my GATT server application is running. Android app has a GATT client which tries to connect to the server using GATT Services.

Comment: right ... so you have no idea why the Android client fails - because it never connects to the pi, the pi doesn't know what errors the Android had